# Exposing a device-wide API to app developers, such as Sonos or Chromecast

Tags: android, ios, api, chromecast, sonos

Installing Sonos or Chromecast enables the compliant apps (called for example Cast senders) to use these kind of streaming APIs.
Now, without going into the details of the specific API, and without necessarily thinking of a multimedia streaming app, let's keep it simple.
What are the ways, on the common platforms such as iOS and Android, to provide the following:

- knowledge to the API-enabled apps that the specific app/service is installed, so its API is usable
- providing a callable, system wide framework/API
- a way of retrieving the list of the apps that use the API, and a way of sending queries to them (Sonos for example can ask for the list of tracks)

On the internet I can find various examples of the client code to use these specific APIs, but nothing about how to build such APIs. Links to docs and examples are more than welcome.